# Reorder data in one column based on data in another column

Tags: oracle

I have the following table structure:

```
create table abc ( Name number , No number )
```

The data is like this:

```
Name | No
-----+-----
 100 |  11
 101 |  20
 102 |  12
 103 |  16
 104 |  13
 105 |  14
 106 |  15
```

I need to retain the *exact values* that are in the `No` column; I just need to modify the records the current values are associated with, so that the `seq` values are in the same order as the `Name` values.

```
Name | No
-----+-----
 100 |  11
 101 |  12
 102 |  13
 103 |  14
 104 |  15
 105 |  16
 106 |  20
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm no pro on Oracle, but yo need something like this wrapped in an [`UPDATE` statement,](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm)

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) FROM dummy )
  AS t1(id, rn)
JOIN ( SELECT seq, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY seq) FROM dummy )
  AS t2(seq, rn)
USING (rn);
```

We look at the two columns `id` and `seq`

- For `id`, we sort by `id`, and return the `row number()` and `id`
- For `seq`, we sort by `seq`, and return the `row_number()` and `seq`

We have the same amount of rows for both, so we'll have the same amount of `row_number()`. Now we just join on `row_number()`. Tie-handling is undefined here.

You should probably rename `seq` to `priority`.

- A `priority` can be static and global depending on the context. The value can matter, as in a priority queue or job scheduler where some priorities hold significance.
- A `seq` by convention usually has gaps so the values **don't matter**, just the comparison (sometimes the uniqueness).

Here is one attempt at making this approach work in Oracle ([dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c62b997e9e9cf813f122339e0017ddbd)):

```
UPDATE
  test tgt
SET
  seq =
  (
    SELECT sortedBySeq.seq
    FROM (SELECT test.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id  ASC) AS rn FROM test) sortedById
    JOIN (SELECT test.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY seq ASC) AS rn FROM test) sortedByseq
      ON sortedById.rn = sortedBySeq.rn
    WHERE sortedById.Id = tgt.Id
  )
;
```

Referencing the same table three times probably won't lend itself well to efficiency, but this is something to start with at least.